# Adding html to a placeholder control on the fly

Tags: asp.net

I am a generic markup which I load at runtime froma file as follows:

```
<div id="pagewidth" >
<div id="header" > Head </div>
        <div id="wrapper" class="clearfix" > 
        <div id="twocols" class="clearfix"> 
            <div id="column2" > Main Content Column </div>
            <div id="column3" > right Column </div>
        </div> 
        <div id="column1" > Left Column </div>
```

Footer

I want to add this to a place holder control in asp.net web page. How do I do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add the html string to an asp:Literal control and then add the literal control to the placeholder's control collection.